# How can I stop CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp") from encoding HTML?

Tags: json, ms-access, vba

I have a VBA script in MS ACCESS that is getting the JSON output of a web page. Once retrieved I process the data using VBA-JSON and insert it into the Access database. It's working beautifully.

This is my code to retrieve the JSON content:

```
With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    .Open "GET", URL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/html"
    .send
    htm.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    ' Debug.Print .ResponseStream
End With
```

I just ran into a little snag and I can't find a way around it:

Within the values of the JSON, double quotes have been encoded as `&quot;` so as to not break the JSON. The problem is, when I retrieve the JSON content of the page, it is getting encoded to `"`, which makes the JSON invalid.

How can I tell it to not encode those HTML values when retrieving or to simply escape those values so it doesn't break my code? I'm guessing there may be another class I could use that wouldn't have this problem, but after hours of searching, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON is a text format that is completely language independent but uses conventions. A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null. The definition of JSON can be found at http://www.json.org/.

JSON likes double quotes (as string delimiter).

`&quot` is an HTML 'encoding' because HTML doesn't like double quotes, not JSON. If a double quote if contained in a JSON field it takes the HTML form `&quot;` in order to avoid confusion.

So, define a variable as string, `Dim a$` and set `a$ = .responseText` in your code and replace all `&quot` with a single quote, i.e. `CHR$(39)`

```
a$ = Replace (a$, "&quot;", CHR$(39))
```

After that

```
htm.body.innerHTML = a$
```

and you will have a JSON-friendly text file.

Funny note: 
in my answer I had to write `&quot;` as code, elsewhere the editor changed automatically this string to double quote (rendering in HTML!)

Comment: Adding an explanation to your contribution, explaining how your suggestion would solve the problem, would give your Answer more value to the StackOverflow site. Please consider expanding on your "answer"

Comment: In der Kürze liegt die Würze: Brevity is the soul of wit, "Kiss" :-)

Comment: @Cisco, thanks, but I tried `CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")` and `CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")`, both of which had the same problem. Got any other ideas?

Comment: @sdPetersen, I use the above class [CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP"] with 5 or 6 different providers and had no issues with JSON data conversion. It is a large project [more than 500 K code lines] and I have to find the code again. I will try to take a look this evening and will be back to you soon. :-)

Comment: @Cisco, I got it thanks to you! You suggested `a$ = Replace (a$, "&quot;", CHR$(34))` and I had tried that, but it didn't work. Instead of that, I changed it to be `a$ = Replace (a$, "&quot;", "'")` (change the double quote to be a single quote) and it works! It seems it was evaluating the `Chr$(34)` to be `"`, so by changing that to something completely different that doesn't invalidate JSON, it worked! Thanks! Update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Part of the merit is yours. I had not fully understand your problem, now it is clear!